# How to get the headers from the last redirect with PHP's curl functions?

Tags: php, http, curl

If I execute a cURL request that is set to follow redirects and return the headers, it returns the headers for ALL of the redirects.

I only want the last header returned (and the content body). How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the output for "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" in the beginning of the line - this is where your last request will begin. All others will give other HTTP return codes.

Comment: One thing though - what about HTTP 1.0? And is 'OK' a standard message after the 200?

Comment: I'd use something like preg_match('/^HTTP 1\.[01] 200/'... to be sure. Good point on HTTP 1.0. OK is a de-facto standard, however the RFC only specifies the result number (200).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';

$opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HEADER         => true);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$response       = curl_exec($ch);
$redirect_count = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT);
$status         = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response       = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, $redirect_count + 2);
$last_header    = $response[$redirect_count];
if ($status == '200') {
    $body = end($response);
} else {
    $body = '';
}
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Redirects: ' . $redirect_count . '<br />';
echo 'Status: ' . $status . '<br />';
echo 'Last response header:<br />' . $last_header . '<br />';
echo 'Response body:<br />' . htmlspecialchars($body) . '<br />';
echo '</pre>';
```

Of course, you'll need more error checking, such as for timeout, etc.

Comment: What happens if one of the redirect response bodies contains an extra \r\n\r\n?

Comment: What I ended up doing was just following the redirects myself by looping on 301 and 302 responses.

Comment: @m1tkr - That's why the call to explode() contains the limiting argument ($redirect_count + 2).

Comment: @George Edison - That'll work, I'm sure, but with the code I posted you keep all the headers plus the content in one neat array.

Comment: @m1tk4 - After re-reading, I see what you're getting at. I don't believe (but don't know for sure) that any webserver will send a  body with a redirect response (tested with IIS and Apache only). Otherwise it's something that would need to be checked for in actual, non-demo, code.

Comment: @m1tk4 - And, after more testing (with Wireshark), I see that a body, if there is one, is sent, but that curl discards it. So my code works as posted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute your request
2. Take the length of the header from `curl_getinfo`s return value
3. Retrieve the part between the last `\r\n\r\n` (but before the end of the header) and the end of the header as last header

```php
// Step 1: Execute
$fullResponse = curl_exec($ch);

// Step 2: Take the header length
$headerLength = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

// Step 3: Get the last header
$header = substr($fullResponse, 0, $headerLength - 4);
$lastHeader = substr($header, (strrpos($header, "\r\n\r\n") ?: -4) + 4);
```

Of course if you have PHP < 5.3 you have to expand the [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) to an if/else construct.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe more simple way to;

```
$result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);

// drop redirect etc. headers
while (count($result) > 2) {
    array_shift($result);
}

// split headers / body parts
@ list($headers, $body) = $result;
```