# return response code 200 only from CURL using php

Tags: php, curl

i try to return the header response from specific url using CURL function

this is my code

```
$strURL = "http://162.253.132.165";



$resCurl = curl_init();

//set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($resCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL);
curl_setopt($resCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($resCurl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($resCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//get the headers
$strHeaders = curl_exec($resCurl);

//close cURL
curl_close($resCurl);

echo $strHeaders;
```

[image]

the problem is that i need only the success response output for 200 OK

and i use this for SSL and https protocols
how i can do that ?

Comment: Or more literally: [How to get the headers from the last redirect with PHP's curl functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3326774)

Comment: echo curl_getinfo($resCurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: mario , when u use the https with get_headers not working :/ ,, that's why i use curl  , they also it's more speed

Comment: _"i need only the success response output for 200 OK"_ - then you should probably make that a HEAD request in the first place ... (especially since you're after "speed" as well.)